# Primeng calendar popping up multiple calendars

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

I don't know why but when I click the input box for the calendar, first time it shows a single calendar but when I click the input box second time it opens another calendar and so on. I am using webpack and angular 4

date-picker.component.html

```
<div class="ui-g">
 <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
   <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="fromDate" ></p-calendar>
 </div>
</div>
```

date-picker.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from 
'@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'date-picker',
 templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html' 
})

export class DatePickerComponent {
  public fromDate: Date;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. The problem was not directly connected with primeng library.
In my case a variable (not used by calendar) was not initialised:

> ERROR TypeError: this.tasks is undefined

I saw this error in the browser console, fixed it and calendar works perfectly.
So I propose, check the browser console for any errors and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with primeng calendar it does not work same as ES standards while date picking. When it is 1/1/2014 in the model date. Typescript tries to insert 1/1/2014 but datepicker does not take it, and it expects 01/01/2014.

I faced similar issues with Primeng the format happens with in primeng and the errors are different. Sometimes it does say Error found at index 0. or some other weird errors

Struck! I feel the issue is same with bootstrap datepicker.